# Firestore not recognizing fields properly

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, querying

So my goal is to have purchased events show certain buttons when the detailsVC of the tableview cell loads and the non-purchased events show a different button. So what I did in this situation was do a query call to the documents in a collection path with the field `purchased` : `true`, and that if there was an error, handle it, but if there wasn't, show the buttons for the purchased events.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
    cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
   
    
    getSchoolDocumentID { (id) in
        if let ident = id {
            self.db.collection("school_users/\(ident)/events").whereField("purchased", isEqualTo: true).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("There was an error fetching the docs: \(error)")
                } else {
                    self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
                    self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
                    self.purchaseTicketButton.isHidden = true
                    self.creditCard.isHidden = true
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

So I ran this thinking it would work, I only have 1 document out of 4 in the collection that has the field `purchased` equal to `true`, so i expected when I clicked on the cell with that field being `true` in my tableVC, the details VC would display the proper buttons. The detailsVC displayed the proper buttons, but when i left the VC and clicked another cell that had the `purchased` field as `false`, I was quite confused to why the buttons were showing up. If anybody can explain to me why that happens or point out an issue with my code that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what I did for this to work was refactor the query, instead of getting documents, just get a single doc. I then used this function and it works like beauty! :)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
    cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
    
    getSchoolDocumentID { (schoolDocID) in
        if let schID = schoolDocID {
            self.db.document("school_users/\(schID)/events/\(self.selectedEventID!)").getDocument { (documentSnapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("There was an error fetching the document: \(error)")
                } else {
                    
                    guard let docSnap = documentSnapshot!.get("purchased") else {
                        return
                    }
                    if docSnap as! Bool == true {
                        self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
                        self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
                        self.creditCard.isHidden = true
                        self.purchaseTicketButton.isHidden = true
                        
                    } else {
                        self.creditCard.isHidden = false
                        self.purchaseTicketButton.isHidden = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This gets the job done perfectly.

Comment: The answer changes the parameters of the question - which is fine but the general approach should be changed. Your comment to my answer was *So if a purchase is made, the buttons show up for only that document* - if that's the case you want to add a observer (aka listener) to the collection so you're app will be notified when data changes. e.g. when the user makes a purchase, that's written to Firebase which then notifies the app (or all apps) the purchase has been made. The document that was modified is presented to the app so you can update the UI based on the changes.

Comment: yeah I have a new issue. I was thinking of doing what you said, but if you add a snapShotListener to a query and then call an updateData() method call, which is what I need to do with the purchase field, it creates an infinity loop. I made this mistake before and used up my daily Firestore read quota in 1 hour lol. I am going to post my new issue, take a look when you have the chance. Thanks for the help. @Jay

Comment: You are correct but that's not the right sequence. Add a listener, update the data and when you receive the event, update your datasource and then call a tableView refresh. e.g. wait until you get the data from firestore and within it's closure update the datasource with the new data and refresh the tableView.

Comment: Is this an answer suggestion for this question or my most recent one?  If it is for this one, can you add a code snippet as your answer? @Jay

Comment: If it is for this one, disregard the question and check my most recent, don't add a code snippet. @Jay

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're assuming the code in the closure will not run if no matches are found, which is incorrect.

Firestore query closures will always run the code inside the closure whether there are results or not.

Here's an example code flow

```
self.db.collection("school_users/\(ident)/events")... { querySnapshot, error
   // handle error

  // the below code always runs (unless there was an error handled above)   
  let docs = querySnapshot?.documents
  print(docs!.count) //will print 0 if no results, or the number of results
}
```

So in your question this code runs every time as long as there was no error and regardless of the contents of the snapshot;

```
self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
self.purchaseTicketButton.isHidden = true
self.creditCard.isHidden = true
```

So this would do it

```
self.db.collection("school_users/\(ident)/events").whereField("purchased", isEqualTo: true).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("There was an error fetching the docs: \(error)")
        return
    }

    guard let docs = querySnapshot?.documents else { return }

    for doc in docs { //for testing to examine the returned docs, if any
       print(doc)
    }

    if docs.count > 0 {
        self.viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
        self.cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
        self.purchaseTicketButton.isHidden = true
        self.creditCard.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, it still doesn't work. @Jay

Comment: as a beginner, I understood the explanation and had a feeling that was the case and I also understood the code as well, but the result of the app functionality hasn't changed at all. @Jay

Comment: @dsonawave There could be a number of issues but most likely your query is returning docs when you think there are none, hence count being greater than 0. You can do some troubleshooting by examining the contents of querySnapshot within the closure. I added a for loop that just prints those contents - add that code and run your app. If you see something printed, then the issue is with your query and it's returning results when you expect none.

Comment: Ok so i added the for loop and just added .data() to the doc so i can see the actual info, and it prints one document because I just purchased it, meaning there is something wrong with my query. How would i know exactly what's wrong with my query? The path is correct because I used the same path in other queries and it does what I expect, so i'm not sure where the problem can really be. @Jay

Comment: Ok I basically understand what's going on and messed up, if there's one or more documents where the field purchased = true, then all the documents will have those methods affected on them. I basically want to differentiate one by one, I tried UserDefaults but it didn't work for what I want to do, so I want to know if it's possible in Firestore. So if a purchase is made, the buttons show up for only that document, not all of them. Is that possible in Firestore with a query call or would I use something different? @Jay